# How to remap the shortcut of switching code completion items from the arrow keys to others? (Tab key for example)

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm a vim user so I use VimMode in IntelliJ. But the way in IntelliJ to select from hints list is using arrow up and arrow down. That bothers me a lots. Is there any way to use tab instead?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. I've tried to configure it. By default it triggers live templates for example, however even when I changed it to trigger it by space it still activated it when I pressed Tab. Perhaps if you mess around more with the keymap it might be possible... (make sure to make a backup of your settings before you mess around too much ;-)) I like the idea though, I have trouble finding the arrow keys too so it sounds like a good alternative!